# Which grammar concept is the sentence "Knowing that I’m on a diet, Maggie sent me some nonfat snacks" using?

Tags: grammar

> Knowing that I’m on a diet, Maggie sent me some nonfat snacks.

The first part of the sentence is in present tense while the second part is past tense. Which English grammar concept is this sentence using?

Can I write:

> Knowing that I was on a diet, Maggie sent me some nonfat snacks.

?

Comment: The first part is *Past Continuous*.  It means Maggie knew in the past, at the point she shared snacks, and Maggie continues to know now at some point after she shared snacks.  It also, and more importantly, means the writer is still on a diet.  This is conveyed to the reader by letting you know that Maggie still knows the writer is on a diet.  You will want to get familiar with these odd English tenses.

Comment: Time and tense are completely different. You use tense to specify time. For example, a present tense to specify future time. The first part of your sentence is a non finite clause and hence it is untensed. By itself it doesn't specify any time. It depends on the matrix clause to locate time. That non finite clause functions as an adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

As EllieK said, it's the continuous past tense, indicating that when Maggie shared snacks, she knew of the speaker's diet, and the speaker is still on said diet.

> Since she knew I was on a diet, she sent me some nonfat snacks

Notice how this sentence, on the other hand, does not indicate that the writer is *still* on a diet.